# Referencing a morph in Squeak (Mophic) created by direct manipulation via 'code'

Tags: smalltalk, squeak, morphic

How do I reference (i.e. program) a Morph created by direct manipulation, for instance dragging a text box from the supplies menu to the desktop, via Squeak/Smalltalk code in say the workspace?  I'm okay (well sort of - I'm just learning Morphic) when I instantiate a Morph  via Squeak/Smalltalk code but I'm at a loss when I've dragged a Morph into existence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Mike Stramba on the Squeak mailing list for the following:-

Drag and dropping the morph on a workspace is good start (you have to
click on the "square" in the workspace header, and turn on the "create
textual reference to dropped morphs" option).

Also when you create the morph it gets added to the current "desktop"
(world) submorphs instance variable.

You can MMB  on the "desktop", click the debug tab and explore the
current world.  You'll see it's a PasteUpMorph.

You can get all the PasteUpMorphs in the image with : p :=
PasteUpMorph allInstances, which returns an array of all the projects
"desktops" in the image.